# Weird yellow shapes in the viewport after launch

Tags: 3d-view

Since a few days, when I launch blender, I see this yellow weird shapes in the viewport. After a few minutes, they simply disappear. I have tried to reinstall blender with different versions, but the problem persists. The graphics card drivers are updated. My CPU and GPU specs are the same than a year ago, but I've never encountered this problem before...

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe gpu drivers changed/broken? it could be some opengl issue... does it change if you select another object, or change view/zoom?

Comment: same problem if I rotate, change zoom, select another object. If I switch to render view mode it's fine, the yellow shapes disappear, but once I return to solid mode the shapes are still there.

Comment: If you wish, can share your file (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link), so we can check if something looks wrong (eg: file corrupt), but I guess about opengl broken.

Comment: I've just uploaded a .blend file (it's just a simple Blender's default startup file; on my PC it shows just the same strange yellow shapes). I guess you're right and that the problem must be related with opengl... Thanks for your quick reply, m.ardito!

Comment: the file has no issues at all. Opengl issue, quite sure.

Comment: What are your system specs?

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to mention it. My PC specs are the following: intel core i7 6950X, 64 RAM Gb, NVIDIA TITAN X Pascal.